# Can (quantum) angular momentum $L$ be zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

I am trying to calculate the *orbital magnetic moment*, $\bar{\mu}$, for Sodium, which has an electron configuration of $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^1$. The full shells do not contribute to $\bar{L}$ and $\bar{S}$ so only the outer shell electron will contribute to them.

The $3s$ shell corresponds to $l=0$. And $\bar{L}=\hbar\sqrt{l(l+1)}$ which gives $\bar{L}=0$.

Is this possible? Doesn't that mean that the electron isn't "orbiting" the nucleus? I am thinking that $\bar{L}^2$ tells you if the electron is "orbiting" the nuclues, but then what is the significance of $\bar{L}$?

**Extra question:**

The z-component of the orbital magnetic moment is given by $\mu_z = -m_l\mu_b$. Since $m_l$ varies as $-l\le m_l\le l$ does that mean that there is more than one value for the z-component? Strange, no?

Comment: Electrons don't orbit the atom like planets orbiting a star. The electrons in atoms exist as a delocalised probability distribution. This distribution can have a zero or non-zero angular momentum, but the latter can't be simply interpreted as the electrons circling the nucleus.

Comment: @JohnRennie You're right, I was being lazy. I added speech marks to make it a little bit more formal :)

Comment: My point was that $L$ is just the angular momentum of the **atomic orbital**, and it can indeed be zero so the total orbital angular momentum of a sodium atom is zero. Why is it strange that $L_z$ can vary from $-L$ to $L$?

Comment: Well I was more concerned with $\mu_z$. Since $m_l$ varies between $-l$ and $l$, I see why there can be a sign change but in cases where $l=2$ you can get four values (two for the positive "side" and two for the negative). What does that mean in physical terms for the electron?

Comment: For $l = 2$ there are of course five values; you missed $l_z = 0$. Anyhow, the $l_z$ value just gives the angle the magnetic dipole makes with the $z$ axis i.e. it's the $z$ component of $l$. Classically this angle is continuous but in QM it's quantised.

Comment: So the magnetic dipole can *take* one (and only one) of those values? I.e: if we "looked" at the electron, it won't have a magnetic moment around *all* the allowed values, but just one of them? Am I interpreting it correctly?

Comment: The magnetic dipole can take any of the $2l + 1$ angles (i.e. values of $l_z$) to the $z$ axis available to it. Indeed an NMR spectrometer works by measuring the energy of the transitions between different $l_z$ values.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#/media/File:Neon_orbitals.png).

Comment: @turnip For $L$=2 you have in fact five, not four, possible values for $L_z$ including zero. What in means in "physical terms" is difficult to say. There are five different orbitals with the same $L^2$  if $L=2$. Anyway, if you count the spin which is 1/2 you have in fact two states (2s+1=2 if s=1/2), $s_z=1/2$ and $s_z=-1/2$. In the case of half-integer spin, the integer value zero cannot be taken, only for integer angular momentum is the value zero allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the quantum angular momentum can be zero.
But it seems you were trapped by your intuition from classical mechanics.

In classical mechanics an orbit with zero angular momentum
means an orbit with a purely radial motion, i.e. kind of a degenerate
ellipse with eccentricity $=1$.
To show what I mean, here are elliptical orbits with [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity)
$0.99$ and $1$. (The nucleus is marked as a red dot)
[image]

But in quantum mechanics an orbital with $l=0$ (also called an $s$-orbital)
is somewhat different. It is a wave function with spherical symmetry.
[image]
<sub>(image from [LibreTexts Chemistry - 6.6: 3D Representation of orbitals](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/06%3A_Electronic_Structure_of_Atoms/6.06%3A_3D_Representation_of_Orbitals))</sub>

To get a crude intuition, you may think of the $s$-orbital as a
superposition of the classical degenerate ellipses from above,
averaged over all possible radial directions.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as: how can an electron orbital have zero angular momentum?
For a classical orbit, zero AM means that the motion is strictly radial. If any motion can be associated with an s-orbital it should be strictly radial motion.

Answer (score -2):

Zero value to angular momentum doesn't mean that the electron is not revolving around the nucleus. It means that the motion of the electron is such that there is no preferred direction in space. For example, in a spherically symmetric orbital and that's exactly what s orbital is. Since s orbital is spherically symmetric there is no particular direction in space, which the angular momentum vector is pointing to and thus its average value is 0.

Comment: it's perfectly possible for a *single* electron to have $\ell=0$.  In fact this is the case for the ground state of hydrogen.

Comment: This is not correct. The statement 'the angular momentum vectors cancel over time' has no meaning.

Comment: Quantum angular momentum cannot be discussed from the classical perspective that the electron is a localized particle.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/374329)

Comment: Ok, I do see that I've treated electron as classical particle in my answer, but what "cancel over time" means is that the average value is zero.